# reading JSONTable from web service parameter in C#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net

I have developed a web service for quiz and this web service is being used by mobile app

```
{"UserCode":"a1123","ExamCode":"597","Answer":[{"Answer":"Answer 1","QuestionID":"8075"},{"Answer":"Nil moratorium","QuestionID":"8076"}]}
```

this is the JSON the mobile app is returning as application/json format and with post method

```
public string QuestionOption_Upsert(string UserCode, string ExamCode, String Answer)
```

above function is taking the data returned by web service

Using C# to get this done 
any help would be appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: it's not clear. can you explain more?

Comment: the json is what i am sending from mobile to the web service and the function takes thee value.
thank you for concern @AmitKumarGhosh however i have solved the problem see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string QuestionOption_Upsert(string UserCode, string ExamCode, QuesAnswer[] Answer);
```

the class QuesAnswer:

```
[DataContract]
public class QuesAnswer
{
    [DataMember (Name="Answer")]
    public int Answer { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "QuestionID")]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; } 

}
```